# Draggable element on custom path

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to create a draggable object that follows a custom path in a browser. You can compare it to the old iPhone slide-to-unlock thing.

[image]

Just not on a straight line but on a for example SVG-path. What would be the best approach to doing this? Maybe anybody knows a nice library for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Would this libary help

[Plain Draggable homepage](https://anseki.github.io/plain-draggable/)

[Plain Draggable github](https://github.com/anseki/plain-draggable)

Comment: I think library as answer is not valid. Maybe a comment.